# Maven and Class not found exception while running .jar file

Tags: java, maven, exception

I started learning maven with simple hello world app and added some dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

And changed `System.out.println("Hello World")` to:

```
    var logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);
    logger.info("Hello World");
```

Then I created .jar file using maven lifecycle and when I try to run it I get this error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at io.github.mat3e.App.main(App.java:11)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at           java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 1 more
```

Why is that?

Comment: Where are you defining `slf4j.version` and have you tried hard coding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommended way to use SLF4J logger API by adding following dependency :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

In your java class fetch the logger instance as follows :

```
 private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class); 
 logger.info("Hello World");
```

Should work fine.

check out the [documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/introduction.html)